# How to delete the file contents (not file, need same inode) in Java and then truncate the file to a specific size (say 38 bytes)

Tags: java, file, truncate, r.java-file

I want to achieve the following in Java realm:

- Open a non-zero sized file.
- Delete all its contents.
- Truncate the same file to a given size (Say 38 bytes ....)
- Somehow, if I delete the contents (works), even if I issue truncate after that, its not honored and file size stays 0.

  ```
      String fileName = "/home/me/dummy/a.1";
      try {
           Long size = 0L;

           // file exists already
           RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(fileName, "rw");
           // set the file pointer at 0 position
           raf.seek(0);
           // print current length
           size = raf.length();
           System.out.println("Before deleting -  fileSize = " + size);

           // set the file length to 0
           raf.setLength(0);
           // print the new length
           System.out.println("After deleting - filesize = " + raf.length());
           raf.close();


          // truncating file to Size = 38 bytes
          FileChannel outChan = new FileOutputStream(fileName, true).getChannel();
          System.out.println("Before Truncating - File size = "+outChan.size());
          outChan.truncate(38);
          System.out.println("Aftre truncating  - File size = "+outChan.size());
          outChan.close();

      } catch (IOException e) {
              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
              e.printStackTrace();
      }
  ```

My O/Ps :

Before deleting -  fileSize = 21

After deleting - filesize = 0

Before Truncating - File size = 0

Aftre truncating  - File size = 0

I have tried multiple other options like :

1. Truncating the file to 0 and then to say 38 bytes (non-zero value that i want)

   ```
           // truncating file to Size = 0 bytes and then to 38 bytes
           FileChannel outChan = new FileOutputStream(fileName, true).getChannel();
           System.out.println("Before Truncating - File size = "+outChan.size());
           outChan.truncate(0);                
           outChan.truncate(38);
           System.out.println("Aftre truncating  - File size = "+outChan.size());
           outChan.close();
   ```

Doesn't work. File Size stays 0. Only 1st truncate is honored.

2. Truncate the file to 0, close the channel, open the channel again and truncate to 38 bytes.

```
            FileChannel outChan = new FileOutputStream(fileName, true).getChannel();
            System.out.println("Before Truncating - File size = "+outChan.size());
            outChan.truncate(0);    
            outChan.close();
             FileChannel outChan1 = new FileOutputStream(fileName, true).getChannel();          
            outChan1.truncate(38);
            System.out.println("Aftre truncating  - File size = "+outChan1.size());
            outChan.close();
```

Doesn't work. File Size stays 0. Only 1st truncate is honored.

Your inputs on how can I delete the file contents and truncate it to a non-zero size. It would b great if i can do it in only one open unlike opening it as (RandomAccessFile and then as FileChannel).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting from [`FileChannel.truncate` javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#truncate(long)):

> If the given size is greater than or equal to the file's current size then the file is not modified.

Since you emptied the file before truncating, its size will be 0. `38 > 0`, so issuing a `.trucate(38)` will result in a no-op.

Either you truncate to 38 bytes without trucating to 0 first, or you truncate to 0 and write 38 bytes to it (e.g. 38 zeroes).

Answer (score 0):

> - Delete all its contents.
> - Truncate the same file to a given size (Say 38 bytes ....)

So the question is, how would one delete a file's content without deleting the file and while also retaining the ability to truncate the file? This is my take on it:

```
String fileName = "/home/me/dummy/a.1";
// file exists already
RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(fileName, "rw");
try {
    // set the file pointer at 0 position
    raf.seek(0);
    // print current length
    long size = raf.length();
    System.out.println("Before deleting -  fileSize = " + size);

    // delete file content
    raf.setLength(0);
    // truncate file to 38
    raf.setLength(Math.min(size, 38));
    // print the new length
    System.out.println("After deleting - filesize = " + raf.length());

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    raf.close();
}
```

What do you guys think; does that satisfy the seemingly conflicting requirements?

Comment: Close, but not the same. He's closing the file after truncating to 0, then opening it and trying to "un-truncate" an already saved file. More importantly, this works.

Answer (score 0):

According to the last code with RandomAccessFile:

The first action setLength(0) removes all physical blocks of 512 bytes occupied by the file on the medium before it was opened.

The second action setLength(38) allocates one physical block (512 bytes) to the file; this block is filled with zeros, the first 38 bytes of which go into the RAM.

The allocated block is very likely not the block from the previous set that made up the same file before it was opened. Thus, it is impossible to retrieve old information.

This requires block-by-block access operations at the lower level of the file system API.

It can be argued that a setLength(SIZE) operation with a SIZE greater than the file length always gets new bytes filled with zeros.